# Tkinter application quits unexpectedly. error "Paattajahaku quit unexpectedly."

Tags: python, tkinter, py2app

I'm relatively new to Python and this is my first application. The code works well when run though terminal and in Pycharm but when I packaged it using Py2app and tied launching it through the file created "Paattajahaku.app" I get the message "Paattajahaku quit unexpectedly." Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
from random import randint

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tkinter open file dialog")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.geometry("300x150")

titleslist = []
nameslist = []
fonrlist = []
df = pd.DataFrame(titleslist)


def select_file():
    filetypes = (
        ("text files", "*txt",
         "excel files", "*xlsx")
    )

    filename = fd.askopenfile(
        title="open a file",
        initialdir="/",
        )
    print("Please wait...")
    for files in filename:
        newfo_nr = files.strip().zfill(8)
        fonrlist.append(newfo_nr)
        sleep(randint(2, 4))  # sleep for a random time
        url = f"https://www.asiakastieto.fi/yritykset/fi/{newfo_nr}/paattajat"
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = bs(page.content, "html.parser")
        names = soup.find_all(attrs={"data-title": "Nimi"})
        titles = soup.find_all(attrs={"data-title": "Asema"})
        for title in titles:
            titleslist.append(title.text)
            for name in names:
                nameslist.append(name.text)
                number_of_names = len(nameslist)
                number_of_fo_nr = len(fonrlist)
                sumfo = number_of_names - number_of_fo_nr
                for i in range(sumfo):
                    if i < sumfo:
                        fonrlist.append(newfo_nr.strip())
                        if title == " ":
                            break
                else:
                    continue
                break
            else:
                continue
            break
        else:
            continue
        break
    print("Files saved")
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(fonrlist, titleslist, nameslist))) # works

    try:
        # with block automatically closes file
        with fd.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".xlsx") as file:
            df.to_excel(file.name)
    except AttributeError:
        # if user cancels save, filedialog returns None rather than a file object, and the 'with' will raise an error
        print("The user cancelled save")


def saveFile():
    try:
        # with block automatically closes file
        with fd.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".xlsx") as file:
            df.to_excel(file.name, index=False, header=False)
    except AttributeError:
        # if user cancels save, filedialog returns None rather than a file object, and the 'with' will raise an error
        print("The user cancelled save")


open_button = ttk.Button(
    root,
    text="Open a file",
    command=select_file
)
exit_button = ttk.Button(
    root,
    text="Exit",
    command=root.destroy
)
open_button.pack(expand=True)
exit_button.pack(expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I used PyInstaller to create the application and it worked.